# Is the body expression more efficient than the simple return of a member variable?

Tags: c#, .net

Having the class with the variable and the method like this:

```
class TheClass
{
    protected string tag_;
    ...
    public string Tag()
    {
        return tag_;
    }
}
```

the IDE suggests to replace the `Tag()` method definition like this:

```
class TheClass
{
    protected string tag_;
    ...
    public string Tag() => tag_;
}
```

What are the pros and cons? Is the result of compilation and/or optimization of both versions the same?

Comment: Once compiled, the two end up in identical IL code.

Comment: You do understand when the IDE suggest something, is just a syntactic sugar.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa Not all IDE suggestions are syntactic sugar, although many of them are.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa - not all the time and also depending on the IDE

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa I am not sure. I can imagine that some suggestions may actually be more efficient.

Comment: I am not the IDE but I suggest you don't put underscore at the end of field name, it looks horrible.

Comment: @SelmanGenç: C++ habit (where it makes sense). On the other hand, the look is not as important as the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second code snippet is a pure syntactic sugar added in C# 6.0. That means it compiles to the exact same IL code as the first snippet and there is absolutely no difference in performance (or otherwise) at runtime. Use whatever style you like.